# Countplot showing same name values as different bars when it should be shown as one bar. How should I solve this problem?

Tags: plot, graph, data-science, eda

I am working with a dataframe of colors which looks like this:

[image: color dataset preview]

However while using `countplot()`  the resultant graph turns out to be like this...

```
plt.figure(figsize=(8,12))
sns.countplot(y="favorite color",data=col_fav_color)
```

[image: countplot]

Notice how instead of one bar for the color "black", there are multiple bars. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Getting rid of the spaces, and mapping the column values helped.